# How to fix AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme in Android

Tags: android, kotlin

In my application I have **background service** and into this service I want show **MaterialButton**. 
I write below codes, but after start service show me below error :

```
View class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton is an AppCompat widget that can only be used with a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant).
```

My XML code:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/gotoStepsBtn"
    style="@style/BlueGradientButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_40mdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10mdp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10mdp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5mdp"
    android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/_25mdp"
    android:text="@string/seeTasks"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_11font_mdp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/scrollLay" />
```

Style code:

```
<style name="BlueGradientButton" parent="ColoredShadowDark">
    <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
    <item name="backgroundTint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_rounded_blue_gradient</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/_12font_mdp</item>
</style>
```

Theme code:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Normally, a service does not have a UI. You might consider editing your question and expanding your [mcve] to show how you are attempting to use that layout resource from a service.

Comment: @CommonsWare, Yes I know a service dose not have a UI ! But in my application and scenario I needed this and I should show UI with custom style !

Comment: You should have there the theme as set in manifest, but you can also create ContextThemeWrapper passing theme that definitely descend from material/appcompat and pass that context to layout inflater instead of passing service context directly

Comment: @V-master manifest theme `android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApp"` can you help me with send code? please

Comment: I could use some more code, of how do you create UI in service currently. It is very uncommon to see service create UI components, as the service was not intended to do so. You should probably reconsider what your service is doing and have activity bind to service instead and communicate with activity to show that view

Comment: @V-master I want show some UIs out of my application. do you have any recommend for this?

Comment: example of usage of theme wrapper: `LayoutInflater.from(ContextThemeWrapper(this, R.style.AppTheme_MyApp)).inflate(R.layout.floating_layout)` as you can see it creates new context that have all the values from Theme.MyApp and is passed into inflater that can inflate xml layout in example floating_layout.xml